# epson v500 digital ice turns off automatically

Tags: film, negative-scanner

I have an Epson v500 and whenever I go to scan negatives I turn digital ice on and press preview. After the preview is done digital ice gets automatically turned off. Is this normal and should I be manually re-turning on digital ice before scanning fullsize?

Comment: Not posting this as an answer, but I'm not a fan of digital ice.  It takes the scanner a lot longer to scan the image and in general creates some artifacts.  B&W + Ice = banded rings of halo effects.  Color + Ice = not too different from 4x oversampled color.  I personally would scan the set in as "proofs" so to speed, and when I decide I want one in high quality I take the time on that one frame.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What type of film are you scanning?

ICE uses an infrared channel to detect defects, and some films (notably ALL traditional B+W films and kodachrome) won't work with the technology.

If you've set the scanner to B+W film it may automatically disable ICE?

Comment: im using medium format, kodak porta nc film. scanner is set to color negatives.

Comment: i think this is on the right track. i don't think my photos need ICE and the scanner was trying to tell me that.